# Image Being Appended and Removed But Text Not being Removed jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, append

So here's my code:

```
<input type = checkbox id = "kinch" name = "link" > Bunz </input>
<div id = bootypipe></div>
```

Here's the JavaScript:

```
$("#kinch").click(function(){

    if ($("#kinch").is(":checked")) {

        //Add image to div bootypipe
         $("#bootypipe").append("<image id = 'chink' src = 'http://4.bp.blogspot.com/_TUdhYRa2Xm0/RsuDa4NvSEI/AAAAAAAAAQs/jr_r6v_SUgs/s320/New-England-Style-Hot-Dog-Buns_8A827671.jpg'>HA!</image>");

    } else {


        $("#chink").remove();

    }
});
```

Here's the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/shrimpboyho/wUu34/13/

The image removes and appends, but when I remove the image the text `Ha!` still stays and builds up over time. How can I remove this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cant you just do :

```
$("#bootypipe").empty();
```

instead of removing image.

Answer (score 2):

Because you only remove the image tag not the text. You could do like this

wrap the image and text with one div and then remove the div tag like

```
$("#kinch").click(function(){

    if ($("#kinch").is(":checked")) {

        //Add image to div bootypipe
         $("#bootypipe").append("<div id='chink_outer'><img id = 'chink' src = 'http://4.bp.blogspot.com/_TUdhYRa2Xm0/RsuDa4NvSEI/AAAAAAAAAQs/jr_r6v_SUgs/s320/New-England-Style-Hot-Dog-Buns_8A827671.jpg'/>HA!</div>");

    } else {


        $("#chink_outer").remove();

    }
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/muthusamy/wUu34/15/)

Answer (score 1):

```
<image id = 'chink' src = 'http://4.bp.blogspot.com/_TUdhYRa2Xm0/RsuDa4NvSEI/AAAAAAAAAQs/jr_r6v_SUgs/s320/New-England-Style-Hot-Dog-Buns_8A827671.jpg'>HA!</image>
```

is invalid HTML markup; the element can't actually contain text. And the correct tag is `<img>`. I suspect it is actually being interpreted as

```
<img id='chink' src='...' > HA!
```

meaning the text isn't part of the element, and isn't removed with it.

Instead of doing `$('#chink').remove()`, do `$('#bootypipe').empty()` to remove everything you added.

Answer (score 1):

The `<img>` element is self closing, like `<br>` or `<hr>` (your demo code is invalid, as mentioned in another answer).

But your code works, if you just include a wrapper (`<p>`,`<span>`,`<div>`) around the image. Then remove the wrapper (ie `$('p').remove();`). Do not add additional ids, classes (you've already created a function around #kinch. why add to the code?). Just target the wrapper. `$('#chink').parent().remove();` works too, and it's unbiased to what element is the parent.

```
$("#kinch").click(function(){
    if ($("#kinch").is(":checked")) {
        $("#bootypipe").append("<p><image id = 'chink' src = '...'>HA!</p>");
    } else {
        $('p').remove();
        // or $('#chink').parent().remove(); // pick your poison
    }
});
```